# Recomended way to create React-Native-for-Web app?

Tags: react-native, create-react-native-app

I want to create a React web app that may or may not become a native app, and for that I'd like to develop it using React Native for Web. However, I'm not sure what is the best course of action, to keep the native targets a realistic possibility:

- Do I use `react-native init`, then add the web aspects on top of it?
- Do I use `create-react-native-app` and do the same?
- Do I use create a webpack based react-native-for-web app and then add ios or android specific features?

Answer (score 4):

Another option is to use create-react-native-web-app
https://www.npmjs.com/package/create-react-native-web-app

```
$ npm i -g create-react-native-web-app
$ create-react-native-web-app myApp
$ cd myApp
$ npm run web
```

Comment: you can read about it here: https://medium.com/@Or_yoffe/start-writing-react-native-for-web-with-react-native-web-%EF%B8%8F-a000d712a37b

Answer (score 3):

I've been researching this process for the past week. Here are some options I found that might work for you.

#### Option 1

There is the `react-native-web` module which basically allows you to simply code in react-native with web polyfills.

Repo here: https://github.com/necolas/react-native-web

#### Option 2

There's also a template called `re-start` you can use which can set you up with a startpoint that will allow you to code in react-native and build Android, iOS, Web, Windows[UWP] and Electron[macOS, Ubuntu, Windows] apps.
Repo here: https://github.com/react-everywhere/re-start

#### Option 3

If you don't want to use the polyfill option, I actually am working on a build that just simply merges `react-native` and `create-react-app` but you have to separate the logic between the 2 platforms yourself.

Repo here: https://github.com/ReyHaynes/react-redux-web-native

Comment: Thanks @ReyHaynes . I'm pretty sold on `react-native-web`. My question was more about what is the best way to go about setting up the initial project, if you create a web project and add native, or a native project and add web, etc.